# JavaScript sort is duplicating results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a really weird issue where JavaScript sort is duplicating the results.

I am sorting a bunch of divs based on their data attributes depending on the user's choice. I should note that the divs in question are pulled into their container beforehand with ajax.

```
//sort flights
function sortFlights(sortBy) {

    var flightDivs = $(".flight-result");

    if(sortBy == "journey") {
        var sortedFlights = flightDivs.sort(function(a, b){
            return $(a).data("journey")-$(b).data("journey");
        });
    }
    else if(sortBy == "depart") {
        var sortedFlights = flightDivs.sort(function(a, b){
            return $(a).data("departure")-$(b).data("departure");
        });
    }
    else if(sortBy == "arrive") {
        var sortedFlights = flightDivs.sort(function(a, b){
            return $(a).data("arrival")-$(b).data("arrival");
        });
    }
    else {
        var sortedFlights = flightDivs.sort(function(a, b){
            return $(a).data("price")-$(b).data("price");
        });
    }

    $(".flight-result").remove();
    $("#flights-results").append(sortedFlights);
}
```

Here is an example of one of the divs I am sorting:

```
    <div class="flight-result" data-price="127.02" 
data-departure="20161214115500" data-arrival="20161214160000" 
data-stops="0" data-journey="000305"></div>
```

The sort is working correctly, however the results come back twice, for example if I have 1,2,3,4,5 it is returning 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: Can you upload the full code?

Comment: try using `else if `

Comment: Updated with some more code.

Comment: @Ted, thanks, I tried but still have the same result. Really odd!!

Comment: why not else if or maybe switch?

Comment: @Rohan210 no particular reason haha, it isn't affecting the outcome either way, but I've updated the code in the question.

Comment: are you sure that there are no hidden elements with the same class

Comment: `sortBy` doesn't change at any point in the function so `else if` or `switch` wouldn't make any difference. In any case, you'll have to show a complete example that replicates the problem.

Comment: I've added to the question that these are dynamically pulled in with AJAX, if that makes any difference.

Comment: @OwainReed it's working fine in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4o9hyrwn/1/).

Comment: Consider using [`makeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.makearray/) to have `flightDivs` be an array separate from the DOM. A jQuery object is like an array, but not really an array, so using native Array functions like `sort` is risky.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan array function not applied  on object like array ?

Comment: @Mahi I'm not sure what that question means, but I've found that I have fewer issues when I use things like `makeArray` or `Array.prototype.sort.apply(jQueryObject, fn)` rather than calling native Array functions on the jQuery object.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately even after using makeArray I have the same result

Comment: @AlexK thanks for the fiddle, I'm just trying to replicate the issue within it

Comment: I created a plunker with sorting by price and departure, seems to work properly, sort is done with STRINGS not NUMBERS: http://plnkr.co/edit/V59sPPYz1RMThwXJ6m29

Comment: If I create the divs using javascript in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4o9hyrwn/1/) the sorting doesn't work at all...

Comment: @OwainReed Give us the updated fiddle that shows how you're creating the divs.

Comment: @AlexK sorry linked to the wrong one! woops. [here it is](https://jsfiddle.net/4o9hyrwn/3/)

Comment: @OwainReed you have whitespace between `data- price`! Remove it and it will work.

Comment: @AlexK good catch - that works

Answer (score 0):

OK I'm kicking myself in the head - @Rohan210 your suspicion was correct, I had a placeholder div hidden with copies of all of the .flight-result divs in it. After removing it is working properly. DOH.

Here is the final code if anyone is interested: (thanks to AlexK for reminding me how bloated the code was)

```
    function sortFlights(sortBy) {

    var flightDivs = $("#flights-results .flight-result");
    flightDivArray = $.makeArray(flightDivs);

    var sortedFlights = flightDivArray.sort(function(a, b){
        return $(a).data(sortBy)-$(b).data(sortBy);
    });

    $("#flights-results .flight-result").remove();
    $("#flights-results").append(flightDivArray);
}
```